# Excel-VBA get filtered collection from Outlook AddressList

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

**Problem:** 
As it seems to me that [AddressList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210890%28v=office.11%29.aspx) does not have a built-in filter functionality such as, say a [C# DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (DatTableObject.Select(*filter criteria*), i am looking for a way to do this.

The Global Address List I am accessing has around a million entries, and I need to search through it up to 1000 times.

I am using the exchange-user name to find the e-mails of people, using the following code:

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set myNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set aList = myNamespace.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
            Set aEntry = aList.AddressEntries("" + ExchangeName + "") 
            Set exUser = aEntry.GetExchangeUser
```

But it only retrieves me a single AddressEntry, which is a problem when I have several people of the same Exchange name - happens often enough.

**Question:** When I search Global Address List in Outlook, I have everything sorted alphabetically and with good speed, I am presented with all matches starting with the string I type in. How can I get a similar collection in VBA?

Comment: Something tells me the Outlook address list should be queryable using windows search. Not sure if that's right though, or if you can use windows search queries from VBA, I must admit. The basic documentation is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx if you want to take a look, though. You'll need a COM handler for the address list though.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddressEntries` object is a collection of `AddressEntry` objects.
When you index directly into the `AddressEntries` collection as you are, you return a *single* `AddressEntry` object based on the `Index` parameter provided.  The `Index` parameter can either by an index number or it can be the default property of the item.

Since the default property of an `AddressEntry` item is the `.Name` property, the return is whatever the first item in the collection is which matches on the `.Name` property.

---

If you want to return all `AddressEntry` objects in the collection which match on the `.Name` property, you will need to loop through the collection.

Now, in .Net you can iterate over a collection using `For...Next`, and I believe you can do this in VBA as well, but I just can't recall off hand. 
e.g.:

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set myNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set aList = myNamespace.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
            Set aEntries = aList.AddressEntries
            For each aEntry in aEntries
                if aEntry.Name="" + ExchangeName + "" Then
                    'Do something with aEntry object
                End If
            Next
```

If for some reason that doesn't work, you can iterate over the collection using the `GetFirst` and `GetNext` methods.
e.g.:

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set myNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set aList = myNamespace.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
            Set aEntries = aList.AddressEntries
            Set aEntry = aEntries.GetFirst
            Do While Not aEntry is Nothing
                if aEntry.Name="" + ExchangeName + "" Then
                    'Do something with aEntry object
                End If
                Set aEntry = aEntries.GetNext
            Loop
```

---

As for sorting alphabetically, have a look at the [Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210304(v=office.11).aspx).

---

And as far as building functionality where

> ...I am presented with all matches starting with the string I type in.

I'm not sure how you want to "present" the matches, or where you want to type in a string.  But the general idea would be to a create function that takes an input parameter (e.g `"MatchName" As String`) and perform a loop like above to find all matches on that string for whatever property you want to look at, and then you would return an array, or something which you could use to "present" the information.

If you wanted to make it dynamic, so that the list updated "as you typed" you could run the updating procedure from the `KeyPress` event.  In order to not run through the whole collection as you typed in a word, you would probably want to store the array and then with each additional letter typed you could just iterate through that array and remove non-matches (narrow the results).   Before that happened you would probably then need some sort of check to see if a letter was removed, (e.g. checking the length of the string in the textbox) which would tell your program to re-run the check on the `AddressEntries` collection (widen the results).

Anyways, that's kind of a general idea on one way you could do it.